# onConfiguration$FunctionBindingRegistrar : You have defined function definition that does not exist: mongoSink

Tags: functional-programming, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

basically i am switching mongo sink(consumer) app from annotation based approach to functional model using consumer bean.

New  code
@Bean(name="input")
public Consumer<Message<?>>input(MongoDbStoringMessageHandler mongoDbSinkMessageHandler ){
return mongoDbSinkMessageHandler::handleMessage;}

old code :
[oldcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgnFP.png)

}
when i deployed them in scdf  getting this error
1."onConfiguration$FunctionBindingRegistrar : You have defined function definition that does not exist: input
2.onConfiguration$FunctionBindingRegistrar : The function definition 'input' is not valid. The referenced function bean or one of its components does not exist

even after adding this property: app.custom-mongo.spring.cloud.function.definition=input

why i am getting  these kind of errors and mongo sink app is not getting connected to  defined queue

i have added spring definition property of functional model  and tried still getting  same errors

Expectations:
1.why getting function doesnot exists errors
2.why myqueue is not able to connect this mongo sink app

Comment: Try `@Bean(name = "input")` 
Can I suggest creating a small reproducer project and log an issue at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues

Comment: i tried adding bean name too still it is not able to find the consumer bean

Comment: Update on this  , we  need to add @Configuration annotation at class level to tell the spring container that there is one or more bean that needs to be dealt with on runtime . after adding that annotation consumer bean is able to find the consumer bean that we defined